# Image in an email not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have this line in my email.html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('video.png'), "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXhW34KzxL" %>
```

The video.png image is in my images directory in the public directory.

However, the image is not showing up. Why is this? Do I have the wrong path?

The email.html.erb file is in a `user_mailer` directory which is in the `view` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the image and see what the URL is. For emails you can't just use a path, you must specify a full URL.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('http://www.mydomain.com/images/video.png'), "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXhW34KzxL" %>
```

Comment: Can you please post the URL that is getting generated in your email by right clicking on it inside the actual email?

Comment: oh I don't think I actually added the image to my app -_-

Comment: Are you running your rails server in development mode? If so, then you'll need to detect that, or possibly use "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/images/video.png" as your image_tag argument.